# Can I Add Floating Point Values As My Range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Help! I'm fairly new to python and I was wondering can I use floating point values in my range? Here is what I am trying to do.

```
x = float(input("Input number: "))
y = float(input("Input number 2: "))

for row in range(0, 5):
    for column in range(x, x*y):
        print(row, column)
```

but it tells me that expects int instead of float in the (x, x*y) spot. Is it possible to put floating points in my range? If so, how?

Edit: Thanks everyone for your help I got it working now!

Comment: What would `range(1.1, 5.4)` even be?

Comment: I don't know, it errors out saying: range() integer start argument expected, got float.

Comment: *”I don’t know”* - then why are you doing it? What output were you hoping for? And why isn’t the type error enough of a “no” answer for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The reason is that it raises too many questions on what to do with them; the simplest was demonstrated by user2357112's comment, where you didn't know the answer. Another is that there are floating point values where adding 1.0 doesn't produce a different number, because their magnitude exceeds their precision.

```
>>> 2.0**53
9007199254740992.0
>>> 2.0**53+1
9007199254740992.0
```

And that's before we hit the denormalized values, including infinity and not a number.

Faced with restrictions like these, range() was implemented for int only rather than have a bunch of tricky to understand special cases for other types. The main guidelines for these decisions is documented as the Zen of Python, which you can see using `import this`.

Another subtle example is numbers that aren't quite what was entered, such as `0.1`. If you try to take a range from 0 to 1 (exclusive) in steps of 0.1, how many values do you get?

```
>>> sum(0.1 for n in range(10))
0.9999999999999999
>>> i=0
>>> while i<1:
...   print(i)
...   i+=0.1
...
0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: It's valid for `int`. If `2.0**53` was insufficient to exhibit the behaviour on your system you might want to take a look at `sys.float_info.mant_dig`; it's 53 for IEEE double precision floats (which are stored in 64 bits). Note that there is significance to entering `2.0` and not `2`, as the question regards float vs int.

Comment: This far, far below the upper limit of floats! It's a *precision* limit, not a magnitude limit, and it occurs for any value. Python 3's ints have merged with long, and can thus grow limited merely by available memory, but retain a precision of 1. The upper limit (where floats still have a finite value) is something like `sys.float_info.radix**(sys.float_info.max_exp-1)*(sys.float_info.radix-sys.float_info.epsilon)` or spelled more sanely `sys.float_info.max`.

Comment: @YannVernier: That's a complicated way to spell `sys.float_info.max`. :-)

Comment: Right, finally I understand. Of course, it's blatantly obvious. really not thinking clearly - sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

No, the arguments to the range constructor [must be integers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

You can convert your range arguments from floats to ints using functions such as round(), int(), math.floor() and math.ceil().

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways we can go about this:

```
x = float(input("Input number: "))
y = float(input("Input number 2: "))

# Just work with integers counting up by 1
for column in range(int(x), int(x * y)):
    print(row, column)

# Simulate, adjust 10 to whatever number of decimal places you need
for column in range(int(x * 10), int(x * y * 10)):
    print(row, column / 10)

# Use numpy to do a floating point range, with whatever step you need
from numpy import arange

for column in arange(x, x * y, 0.1):
    print(row, column)
```

Answer (score 0):

The range argument expects int as far as I know but for your problem, you could come up with custom range like this

```
import itertools

x = float(input("Input number: "))
y = float(input("Input number 2: "))

def seq(start, end, step):
    assert(step != 0)
    sample_count = abs(end - start) / step
    return itertools.islice(itertools.count(start, step), sample_count)


for row in range(0, 5):
    for column in seq(x,x*y,0.1):# 0.1 is the difference you want in between
        print(row, column)
```